# Panel Template Reuse in Drupal

Tags: drupal

How to create a [Panel template](http://drupal.org/project/panels) ( using Panels Module) in Drupal? The reason I ask this is because I have a Panel template to show information for different faculties. Each Faculty will have the same page layout, but the information displays within the page will be faculty specific.

So I am thinking about passing arguments into the panel template via url and the content will be displayed according to the given parameters.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is admittedly a [cold case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_case), but I will give it a shot, given that nobody else has answered so far and the answer seems straightforward to me! (Maybe I missed something?)

I would say that you should **define a context in panels**, so that all the bits of the display will be able to refer to the same *faculty* and present the right content (this is indeed one of the major advantages of panels over blocks, which do not know what is the rest of the content on the page).

Although this is an old question - and thus you most certainly have chosen and finalised your design - from your question I wonder if you really have to use panels or if you could achieve the same result (but in a less resource-intensive way, which could be an advantage for a busy university site) by implementing a view that will present core information about the faculty and will filter linked nodes with a taxonomy (terms in the taxonomy could be "medicine", "law", "engineering"...)

Well... who knows? I hope at least the OP will see this answer to an old question lost in time... ;)

Answer (score 1):

For searchers ... you can indeed have a single panel with multiple variants.  Each variant is defined by a specific page URL.  Here's how:

1. Define a panel.  Give it a path, like myportal, e.g. for a site whose DNS was www.mysite.com, the path to the panel root would be www.mysite.com/myportal and you would specify just myportal as path
2. Define a variant for one page on the path, e.g. pageFlavorX.  When you define the variant, check the box for selection rule
3. For the selection rule, pick String:URL path.  For paths (using our example) enter the full path from the DNS, e.g. you would enter myportal/pageFlavorX
4. For the variant, configure your layout and content
5. Configure your other variants, saving and testing as you go.  For example, to test your first variant, you'd open a browser tab and hit http://www.mysite.com/myportal/pageFlavorX